# ssh to windows machine and executing a bat file

Tags: perl, cygwin

My .bat file resides in windows and i want to invoke it from Linux through ssh. I have already installed cygwin in windows and i am able to ssh to the machine. I want to write a Perl script to connect to windows server and execute the .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go for this kind of task is [Net::SSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH)

Ex. :

```
use Net::SSH qw(ssh issh sshopen2 sshopen3);

ssh('user@hostname', $command);

issh('user@hostname', $command);

ssh_cmd('user@hostname', $command);
ssh_cmd( {
  user => 'user',
  host => 'host.name',
  command => 'command',
  args => [ '-arg1', '-arg2' ],
  stdin_string => "string\n",
} );

sshopen2('user@hostname', $reader, $writer, $command);

sshopen3('user@hostname', $writer, $reader, $error, $command);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any of:

- [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH): easy to use, does not work on Windows, but it can connect to Windows hosts.
- [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH2): not so easy to use, works anywhere.
- [Net::SSH::Any](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aAny): wrapper for the modules above, with easy to use API. Though, still incomplete.

For example:

```
use Net::SSH::Any;
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Any->new($host, user => $user, password => $password);
my @output = $ssh->capture('c:\foo.bat');
```

Comment: I tired with Net::SSH::Any, but it throws the following error.    Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/lib/perl5/site                                                                                                             /Net/SSH/Any.pm line 388.
        (in cleanup) Goto undefined subroutine &main::DESTROY at /usr/lib/perl5/                                                                                                             .8.8/Net/SSH/Any.pm line 388.

Comment: Could you describe your (local) environment? OS, perl and module versions?